# Не перемещается зона нажатия кнопок в ZoomLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

Я пишу игру "Сапер" на Kotlin. Мне нужен layout, который будет позволять отдалять/приближать или перемещать игровое поле.

Я нашел [ZoomLayout](https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout), но в нем не перемещается зона нажатия кнопок.

Есть ли какой-то другой layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашел в документации. Надо установить `hasClickableChildren = true` и все заработает.